# how to apostrophe with os.system in ffmpeg drawtext in python

Tags: python, os.system, f-string

I just want to execute this code with os.system('command') in ffmpeg drawtext()  but unable to execute it just because of ' (apostrophe) , it fails

The code goes here ->

the \f is working as \n but I'm using that for seprating word

```
from PIL import ImageFont
import os

def create_lines(longline, start, end, fontsize=75, fontfile='OpenSansCondensedBold.ttf'):

    fit = fit_text(longline, 700, fontfile)

    texts = []
    now = 0
    # breaking line on basis of '\f'
    for wordIndex in range(len(fit)):
        if fit[wordIndex] == '\f' or wordIndex == len(fit)-1:
            texts.append(fit[now:wordIndex+1].strip('\f'))
            now = wordIndex

    # adding multiple lines to video
    string = ''
    count = 0
    for line in texts:
        string += f''',drawtext=fontfile={fontfile}:fontsize={fontsize}:text='{line[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuceq.png)}':fontcolor=black:bordercolor=white:borderw=4:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2-100+{count}:'enable=between(t,{start},{end})' '''
        count += 100

    print(string)
    return string

def createVideo(content):
    input_video = 'video.mp4'
    output_video = 'output.mp4'
    font_file = 'BebasKai.ttf'
    text_file = 'OpenSansCondensedBold.ttf'
    font_size = 75
    font_color = 'white'

    part1 = create_lines(content[1], 0.5, 7)
    part2 = create_lines(content[2], 7.5, 10)

    os.system(
        f"""ffmpeg -i {} -vf "drawtext=fontfile={font_file}:fontsize={95}:text={content[0]}:fontcolor={font_color}:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.9:boxborderw=20:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/4-100{str(part1)}{str(part2)}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -t 10 {output_video} -y""")

my_text =['The Brain', "Your brain can't multitask effectively", "Multitasking is a myth,  it's just rapid switching between tasks"]

createVideo(my_text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfldl.png)

what I want is that, I would able to execute this correctly

Comment: Did you try adding a slash, so that it's escaped by the time you feed it to ffmpeg? E.g. `"Multitasking is a myth,  it\\'s just rapid switching between tasks"`. But on a slightly different note: why are you using both `'` and `"` for triple quotes ([per PEP8: use `"` for triple-quoted strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#string-quotes)), and why are you using triple quotes at all if your strings are single line strings?